# Dynamically evaluating string conditions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, string, dynamic

I have a collection of strings. I need to find out from this collection strings which satisfies some condition e.g. that string contains A and B or C. These criteria are specified by the user so they are dynamic. In Linq it should be something like,

```
List<String> items = new List<string> { "sdsdsd", "sdsd", "abc"};

var query = from item in items
            where  item.Contains("a") && item.Contains("b") || item.Contains("c")                         
            select item;
```

I want to make the where condition dynamic so that it can work for any input by the user. Is it possible to do this in C# without using any external library. Maybe using Linq or something else which is builtin into .Net framework.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it on your own, start here:
Dynamic Predicates:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513731.aspx
Dynamic Expression Trees:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

I think this is more than you wanted, and would strongy suggest to use some (lightweight) ready and tested library, that does the conversion from user-strings to runtime-queries for you.

Answer (score 5):

Although you don't want to use external libraries, there is one which is just fantastic, and that is [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). Predicate builder allows you to build up a set of predicates to match items against, e.g.:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<string>();
predicate = predicate
    .And(p => p.Contains("a"))
    .And(p => p.Contains("b"));

var matches = items.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/step2.png))</sub>

You need something like this? Use [the Linq Dynamic Query Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20081011004405/http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) (download includes examples).

Check out [ScottGu's blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) for more examples.